# is image format (suffix) always in url?

Tags: image, url

is image format (suffix) always in url? most of times is so, but when it is not, how the browser understand url is for image? I mean maybe some where in package there is format. is it so or the only way is parsing?
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The extension and in fact the entire URL is completely irrelevant for the format of the image.

Image formats are determined by:

- the "mime type" sent by the server, such as `image/png` or `image/jpeg`.
- the first few bytes in the file contents, which will also tell you the image format. Your image editor (photoshop, etc) applies this type to the file.

Strictly speaking, the server is supposed to send the correct mime type. But most browsers also check the first few bytes of the file.

Comment: Is the mime type always reliable? what happens if server send wrong mime type in the header?

Comment: @user3318731 no, mime types aren't reliable. A misconfigured server will send the wrong one. The only reliable way to know if something is a png/jpg is to look at the contents of the file which is what browsers do if the mime type doesn't make sense.